# Events are not working in Marionette.Layout

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

In my layout, I written an event like in the following way. but it's not working.I don't know where I did wrong.

```
var ProductLayout=Marionette.Layout.extend({
        template:"#archiveBodyTpl",
        regions:{
            productsHeaderContainer:"#archiveHeader",
            productsMiddileContainer:"#archiveBody",
            productsFooterContainer:"#archiveFooter"
        },
        events:{
            "click #ppCloseBtn":"closingProductsDiv"
        },
        closingPlansDiv:function(){
            console.log("closing event");
        }
    });
```

can anyone help me. Thanks.

Comment: which version of marionette are you using and also can you show the template html

Comment: also `closingProductsDiv` is not the name of the method you have called it `closingPlansDiv`

Comment: in the latest marionette version layout name is changed and now you need to use Marionette.LayoutView and are you sure you have tag with id="ppCloseBtn" in your template?

Comment: @Quince Thanks man... Seriously I did very silly mistake. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your events you reference `closingProductsDiv` but you define `closingPlansDiv` so change one or the other so they match i.e

```
events:{
    "click #ppCloseBtn":"closingProductsDiv"
},
closingProductsDiv:function(){
    console.log("closing event");
}
```